# How to param Network on Ubuntu to use both Wifi (for web) and Ethernet (for local network)?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet

My question is a bit know, but I'm a noob about the network (sub-net, gateway, route) and I don't find something clear to help me.

**one computer**
**system: ubuntu 18.04**

I want/need to use simultaneously the wifi for the web (connect to one modem) and Ethernet for local network (link to a switch, himself link to ip camera);
Everything is working but only separately. I have to configure the "route" but I understand nothing. For example, I have tried to remove the gateway from wifi connection, and several thing else but nothing is working, and I hate the random test without understand what is running behind the machine;anyway
If it's possible, and exist a reliable solution, I will be happy;)

The wifi router (internet) is totally different from the switch which connects my Ethernet port to the IP webcam.

-ipv4 IP webcam address (fixed, dhcp off) is: 192.168.1.64, Sub-net Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 192.168.1.1, DNS Server: 8.8.8.8

-ipv4 IP WiFi router address (for internet) is (dhcp on): 192.168.1.1, Sub-net Mask: 255.255.255.0 . For the Gateway and DNS , I don't no but the connection is working with both at 192.168.1.1

Someone could tell me what can I put in those GUI windows and why please? 
Thanks a lot

[GUI network-manager - ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Ri5.png)

Comment: That adds a burden to your PC's CPU you may not like. What you describe is 'routing', and PC hardware is not optimized to route data through different interfaces. You can do it, yes, but it will shift a computing burden from your existing router (which is optimized for that job) to your PC (which is not). Do you want to slow down your PC to do that routing job? If so, start reading https://www.linux.com/news/linux-lan-routing-beginners-part-1/  https://www.linux.com/tutorials/linux-lan-routing-beginners-part-2/  et https://askubuntu.com/a/452755/197910

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, this is a very interesting link. But actually, I don't need to route I think because I just want to have an Ethernet link to a local network, and the wifi for internet. Those networks are so separates. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can! (As The Man would say.) However, your OS will need to route all the local traffic to your Ethernet port and all the other traffic to your WiFi port, so you will need to configure that. Is the WiFi router connecting you to the Internet different from the switch which connects your Ethernet port to the IP webcam, or are they the same? What's the IP address for the WiFi Wireless Access port, your default gateway, & the IP webcam? Please click [edit] and add that info to your original question. Please do not use Add comment; instead, please put it in the question w/ [edit].